# ignoring some dependencies when install with pip

Tags: python, pip

When installing a package with pip, is there a way to ignore (not install) *some* dependencies?

`pip install [some package] --no-deps` ignores all deps... but I'm only interested in ignoring a few.

Comment: i dont really think its a feature that is builtin in pip

Comment: I know it is not what you are looking for, but it may be useful https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find builtin thing for this but maybe i can find workaround that will do this like those:

#### this option is really slow (because johnnydep is slow) but will do the trick

use [johnnydep](https://pypi.org/project/johnnydep/):

```sh
pip install johnnydep
```

and run it as:

```sh
python3 -m johnnydep ipython --output-format pinned -v 0 | grep -e <Your deps regex> | xargs pip install --no-deps
```

this will installed ipython and the deps base on the regex